# Django Template Tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a link in my site that goes to a user's profile page, but right now when logged in it instead goes to the logged in users' profile page. The link is an author's name and I want it so that when clicked on goes to the authors profile page, instead of the logged in users' profile page. I think the problem is in my url template tag for the link (the first  tag in post_index.html ) but I don't know what to do.

post_index.html

```
   {% for post in post_list %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <img class= "rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.profile_pic.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="article-metadata">
#Here!        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'profile' %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.published_date }}</small>
          </div>
          <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <p class="article-content">{{ post.text }}</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Your Account Has Been Updated! ")
            return redirect("profile")

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {"u_form": u_form, "p_form": p_form})
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"
```

Comment: What is `post_list` here? I couldn't see any usage of the same in your given snippet, .

Comment: post_list is my paginated posts on a page

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate model for the Author profile similar to the Profile model you currently have which is for the User ( that’s why it redirects to the logged in user’s profile when you click the link )  and use the author field as a one to one relationship.